# how many installed applications used licence/product key in MacOSX

Tags: macos, cocoa, applescript

I am working on a project in MacOSX, for that project i want to know that how many installed applications used licence/product key in MacOSX?

For example, i have installed MicroSoft Office for my MacOSX, and this application required product key for installing full version.

so I want to know that how many installed applications used product key at time of installation?

is there any path where all product key values are stored in MacOSX?

Comment: So, you basically want analytics for your application? Or you want to know how many licensed applications are on a Mac OS X system?

Comment: I want to know how many licensed applications are there on my Mac OSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know how many users of your application used a product license/key it would be easiest to implement something like [Flurry Analytics](http://www.flurry.com) or [Distimo](http://www.distimo.com) and then manually track how many users are licensed/unlicensed.

---

If you would like to know how many applications that are installed on a computer using Mac OS X are licensed, then that would be difficult. Each software uses other copy protection algorithms/mechaniques and it is intentional for a user not to find out where is the license stored or kept, because then it would be easier to manipulate with and that leads to hacking/cracking  a software.

This would be very very hard, unless you would hardcode a special mechanique for getting the licensed/unlicensed info from specified applications. Otherwise, it is impossible to make it universal for all apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get this information! Each app developer decide on its own how to implement license key validation. They are not stored in the same manner or place. Some could be stored in a plist (which wouldn't be secure), some in KeyChain and others in its very own way.

You could however, if you knew how each app validates its license, check if a particular app is licensed. This would require you figured out how each app is doing it and then program some method to check this.